# Group homomorphism is also ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two rings (not necessarily with unit, so rng i guess?) and $f$ a group homomorphism from $(A,+)$ to $(B,+)$. We also have the property that $f(xy)$ is $f(x)f(y)$ or $f(y)f(x)$ for all x,y in $A$. Prove that $f$ is a ring homomorphism if and only if there exists at least one pair $(a,a')$ of distinct elements in $A$ such as $f(aa')=f(a)f(a')$.

Essentially, we have to prove that if there is one pair for which the "good order" holds, then it holds for all pairs.

I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Don't you at least have to assume that $aa'\neq a'a$?  Otherwise the condition wouldn't tell you anything additional.

Comment: Well to start can you show the case if $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$?

Comment: I don't see how this can be true. Let $R, S, T$ be noncommutative and $f:S\to R$ a ring homomorphism and $g:T\to R$ an antihomomorphism. Then doesn't $f\times g:S\times T\to R\times R$ contradict this?

Comment: @the statement to be proven is independent of if $A$ is commutative or not.

Comment: @marshalcraft: It isn't clear what you are asking.  The condition is that for each pair $(x,y)$, $f(xy)$ is one of $f(x)f(y)$ or $f(y)(x)$, but which one could (as far as what is assumed) depend on the pair. [reply to first comment]

Comment: @marshalcraft: It is trivial if the ring is commutative.

Comment: yes i am sorry about the confusion, it depends on the pair

Comment: @MattSamuel: I don't think the condition holds then, does it?

Comment: @Jonas It seems to me that it does, but it's also 10 pm which makes it likely that I'm incorrect.

Comment: @science3456: Do you see what I mean, it is clearly wrong if $f$ is an antihomomorphism and not a homomorphism but you take $(a,a') = (a,0)$ for any $a\in A$.  Perhaps it should say $f(aa') \neq f(a')f(a)$?

Comment: @Jonas please re think, it says to show that if $f$ a homomorphism then there exists at least one pair $a,a'$ such that $f(a,a')=f(a)f(a')$ provided the conditions that $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ OR the $f(xy)=f(y)f(x)$. Part of proving that requires to show the case that it is true $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: @Matt: If $h=f\times g$, then $h((s_1,t_1)(s_2,t_2))=h(s_1s_2,t_1t_2)=(f(s_1s_2),g(t_1,t_2))=(f(s_1)f(s_2),g(t_2)g(t_1))$, which generally would equal neither $(f(s_1),g(t_1))(f(s_2),g(t_2))$ nor $(f(s_2),g(t_2))(f(s_1),g(t_1))$.

Comment: It appears the question was somewhat badly written. I have although found a very similar one here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398795/almost-ring-homomorphism?rq=1. Thank you for your comments it is very much appreciated!

Comment: @science3456: Yes, thanks.  If you corrected the statement here it would be a duplicate.

Comment: I think the question for groups would be related to the center notion.